# Converting a string to a JSON array using Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have this json string:

```
{"17":{"31":{"price":5,"oldPrice":5,"priceValue":"5.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":5,"includeTax":5},"29":{"price":8,"oldPrice":8,"priceValue":"8.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":8,"includeTax":8},"30":{"price":10,"oldPrice":10,"priceValue":"10.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":10,"includeTax":10}},"12":{"price":0,"oldPrice":0,"priceValue":"0.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":0,"includeTax":0},"11":{"price":0,"oldPrice":0,"priceValue":"0.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":0,"includeTax":0}}
```

How can I convert this to an array using Prototype? I tried evalJSON(), but it did not work.

Comment: Why do you need an array? Accessing it as an object is easy to do.

Comment: How would I acces it as an object?

Comment: If it is a string, you can't. You have to use a JSON parser to deserialize it.

Comment: *Converting a string to a JSON array* ... the title does not make sense at all. Are you trying to **parse** JSON?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built-in [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) should do it,you don't need any library:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is no valid JSON, as it contains two asterisks. Remove them and apply evalJSON after that:

```
str.substring(1, -1).evalJSON(true);
```

Although I'd say you should use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) (or a polyfill like json2) instead of [`"".evalJSON`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/evalJSON).

And note that you will get back an object, not an array!

Comment: Somebody editied my post, I had it in * and the editor did not removed them. :)